# Postgres complicated query generate case statements

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query like this:

```
select date, meter,
   sum(case when period = 1 then round(value, 2)end) as period_01,
   sum(case when period = 2 then round(value, 2)end) as period_02,
   sum(case when period = 3 then round(value, 2)end) as period_03,
   sum(case when period = 4 then round(value, 2)end) as period_04,
   sum(round(kwh, 2)) as total
from table
group by date, meter
order by date, meter;
```

I need a couple of things:

1. the total column needs to be a sum of the case statements.  Because the case statements are rounded, it is giving the wrong total.
2. is it possible to generate the case statement columns based off of how many periods there are for any given date?  e.g. To look like this based on how many periods for each day

```
Date - MeterId - Periods . . . - Total    
2017-06-05 | meter_01 | 10 | 14 | 6 | {total} 30
2017-06-06 | meter_01 | 10 | 7  | 2 | 5 | {total} 24
```

I guess it would have to first find how many periods there are for each date then run the query but this is way beyond my knowledge level...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your first question is to `round()` *after* the `sum()`:

```
select date, meter,
       round(sum(case when period = 1 then value end), 2) as period_01,
       round(sum(case when period = 2 then value end), 2) as period_02,
       round(sum(case when period = 3 then value end), 2) as period_03,
       round(sum(case when period = 4 then value end), 2) as period_04
       round(sum(kwh), 2) as total
from table
group by date, meter
order by date, meter;
```

The answer to your second question is essentially "not easily".  You can use dynamic SQL, `crosstab()` with a very complicated expression, or put the values into an array/json object.  But there is no easy way to return a variable number of columns.

Comment: I could do it per day as any specified day would have an exact number of periods for every row.  (Most days are 48 but two days per year it is 46 and 50 for daylight savings).

But I would still need to generate the case statements as a function.  Or maybe I could get away with just having three different queries?

Comment: By the way, the rounding still isn't working properly.  The 'value' columns are numeric(20,8) and when I use either method  the totals are out by fractions of a cent in some cases.  I test it by exporting to excel and then totaling the period columns and comparing that to the postgres total  - and they differ.  It is important the totals are exact as it is a validation column.

Comment: @Daryn . . . Don't round the values if you want 8 digits of precision.  Unfortunately, I don't have the confidence that Excel would necessarily be correct in this situation.  You might have to do some investigation to determine which answer is right.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, have managed to resolve with your help.  I just run another query for the dates (2x per year) where there is a differing number of periods.   As for the rounding, I realised my meter readings are only 3dp anyway so changing the rounding to 3 resolved.